# Can a hacker modify any parameters sent as part of an Ajax.ActionLink Call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, jquery

i have the following Ajax.actionlink inside a view to add an answer under a question:-

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Add Answers",
 "Create", "Answer",
new { questionid = question.QuestionID},

new AjaxOptions
{

    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "Get",
    UpdateTargetId = "removetable"
})
```

while will call the following action method:-

```
public ActionResult Create(int questionid)
    {

        ViewBag.IsRight = new SelectList(repository.FindAllAnswerDescription().ToLis(), "IsRight", "description", 1);
        ViewBag.questionid = questionid;
         Answer answer = new Answer();
         return PartialView("_answer",answer); }
```

so my question is will a hacker be able to modify the `new { questionid = question.QuestionID},` parameter send by the ajax link ? and if yes how i can avoid this.
BR

**Edited:-**
i am doing the following check using a helper method (IsauthorizedBy) on the post action method to check if the user is authorized to answer a question or not:-

```
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(int questionid, Answer a)
            {
    q = repository.findquestion(questionid);
    if ((q == null) ||  (!q.IsauthorizedBy(User.Identity.Name))){
return ("error");}
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                repository.AddAnswer(a);
                    repository.Save();
                    return PartialView("_details",a);
                }
return(a);}
```

so will it handel a hacker who will try to modify the question id and answer a question he is not authorized to answer.
BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but you want to ensure on the server side they have access to this question by querying their permissions and some database scheme in place ensuring they have access to this. If it's not feasible then you can use 
Html.AntiModelInjectionFor from
 mvcsecurity.codeplex.com plus 
[ValidateAntiModelInjection()]

Comment: Actually on the POST Create action method i am calling a helper method (.ISAuthorized) which will check if the user has the permission to answer this question or not so even if a hacker modify the question id he will only be able to send his answer to the questions he is authorized to answer . so do u think this approach is enough even if my application is allowing to hack the question Id value without displaying any warnings to the hackers.

Comment: see my update, will it work fine ?,, or there are still some extra checks i should do !!

Comment: that looks fine although you may want to include that in the query: q = repository.findquestion(questionid, userId);   btw using a name rather than an id isnt the best approach, names can changed, but just an fyi, thats up to you: )

Comment: MVC Security Extensions was just the thing I was looking for - thanks Adam

Answer (score 0):

You never trust anything coming from the client-side. Everything can be altered on the way, either in the scripts or on the network.

Since it's only an id, you need to be careful and do extra checks on the server

Comment: what kind of check i should do ?

Comment: I saw your edit and it looks reasonable - I can't think of a better way to do that